# How do I use a custom pip.conf in a docker image?

Tags: python, docker, pip

How can I configure a Docker container to use a custom pip.conf file?

This does not (seem to) work for me:

```
from python:3.9

COPY pip.conf ~/.config/pip/pip.conf
```

where `pip.conf` is a copy of the pip configuration that points to a proprietary package repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `~` expansion. Just define like this, using the dest path explicitly.

```
from python:3.9

COPY pip.conf /root/.config/pip/pip.conf
```

If you want to use something other than `/root/.config` then consider to add a [WORKDIR](https://docs-stage.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) instruction and specify paths relative to that.